# Cannot build project after adding Firebase CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I tried to add Firebase/Core pod to already completed Xcode project but I cannot build it.

My podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target '>>NAME<<' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

and after I install pods and open a created workspace I get the following error:

> ld: framework not found FIRAnalyticsConnector
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

which is apparently a common error if you build a project but I'm 100% convinced I built workspace. Also, I see FIRAnalyticsConnector framework and it's not like it's not there because I see it in the project files... 
I'm hopeless and I didn't find an answer anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Others have solved this by:

Drag and drop FIRAnalyticsConnector framework from the Pods project to the Build Target. See https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/1071#issuecomment-442774801

It would be interesting to know the root cause though, since this problem doesn't typically occur. Does it still occur after removing DerivedData or upgrading to CocoaPods 1.5.3?

Comment: I did the same as implied in the link and I also have 1.5.3 CocoaPods but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Add `$(inherited)` to your Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths for Debug and Release